# Android Studio Out Of Memory Error when i run app

Tags: android, android-drawable, logcat

When i run my application on a physical device 
Every time the application crashes. The LogCat displays "Out of memory and Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16768392 free bytes and 49MB until OOM "

The device I am using is Xiaomi RedMi note 4
3GB RAM
Android version 7.0
Processor Qualcomm Snapdragon 625

Here is the LogCat message

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16768392 free bytes and 49MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:457)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromResourceStream(ResourcesImpl.java:1272)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:743)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:585)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:308)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:785)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
    at com.suman.udit.su.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Comment: show your code and is bitmap too large or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OutOfMemoryError is the most common problem occured in android while especially dealing with bitmaps. This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.

As mentioned by Aleksey, you can add below entities in your manifest file `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` , `android:largeHeap="true"` it will work for some environment's.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

you should definately read some of Androids Developer concept's, specially here:[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://Android:%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream()%20out%20of%20memory%20with%20a%20400KB%20file%20with%202MB%20free%20heap)

Read all 5 topics and rewrite your code again. If it still doesn't work we will be happy to see what you've done wrong with the tutorial material.

Here some of possible answers for these type of errors in SOF

[Android: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() out of memory with a 400KB file with 2MB free heap](http://Android:%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream()%20out%20of%20memory%20with%20a%20400KB%20file%20with%202MB%20free%20heap)

[How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android](http://Android:%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream()%20out%20of%20memory%20with%20a%20400KB%20file%20with%202MB%20free%20heap)

[Android : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](http://Android:%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream()%20out%20of%20memory%20with%20a%20400KB%20file%20with%202MB%20free%20heap)

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](http://Android:%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream()%20out%20of%20memory%20with%20a%20400KB%20file%20with%202MB%20free%20heap)

[Solution for OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget](http://Android:%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream()%20out%20of%20memory%20with%20a%20400KB%20file%20with%202MB%20free%20heap)

Comment: `android:largeHeap="true"` is not appropriate for most apps. That harms the user experience, by prematurely kicking other processes out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Drawable (picture, perhaps?) you are trying to load at `MainActivity.java:52` is too big. You also might try putting it in the [`drawable-nodpi`](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) folder, so that the system doesn't try to re-scale it upon load.